# How to use callables instead of Abstract Factory Pattern in Python?

Tags: python, design-patterns, abstract-factory

I have been trying to figure out when and where to use different patterns in Python. I came across this document: https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/abstract-factory/

Now this made me wonder how can I do what he says in my code. Here is my implementation is an abstract factory. Not sure if its correct.

```
from abc import abstractmethod, ABC

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from managers.database_manager import DatabaseManager
from managers.log_manager import LogManager
from managers.sqlalchemy_manager import get_db
from models.bal.post import Post
from models.dal.models import Post as ORMPost


class PostsManager(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_posts(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def get_post(self, post_id):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def create_post(self, post: Post):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def delete_post(self, post_id):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def update_post(self, post_id, post: Post):
        pass


class PostsManagerFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_posts_manager(use_orm=True) -> PostsManager:
        if use_orm:
            return PostsManagerWithORM()
        else:
            return PostsManagerWithoutORM()


class PostsManagerWithORM(PostsManager):

    def get_posts(self):
        db: Session = get_db()
        posts = db.query(ORMPost).all()
        return posts

    def get_post(self, post_id):
        pass

    def create_post(self, post: Post):
        pass

    def delete_post(self, post_id):
        pass

    def update_post(self, post_id, post: Post):
        pass


class PostsManagerWithoutORM(PostsManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.db_manager = DatabaseManager()

    def get_posts(self):
        posts = self.db_manager.execute_query("select * from posts")
        return posts

    def get_post(self, post_id):
        post = self.db_manager.execute_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id='%s'", (post_id,), single_record_flag=True)
        return post

    def create_post(self, post: Post):
        post = self.db_manager.execute_query("INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (%s, %s) RETURNING *",
                                             (post.title, post.content), single_record_flag=True)

        return post

    def delete_post(self, post_id):
        post = self.db_manager.execute_query("DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = %s RETURNING *", (post_id,),
                                             single_record_flag=True)
        return post

    def update_post(self, post_id, post: Post):
        post = self.db_manager.execute_query(
            "UPDATE posts SET title = %s, content = %s, published = %s WHERE id= %s RETURNING *",
            (post.title, post.content, post.published, post_id),
            single_record_flag=True)
        return post
```

Here is how I am calling these methods:

```
posts_manager = PostsManagerFactory.get_posts_manager()
posts = posts_manager.get_posts()
```

My first question, is it the right way to use abstract factory pattern? If, not please let me know, I will probably ask a new question. Anyway if it is, why does that document say about using callables is better than using abstract factory pattern, how do I do that in this case?

Comment: As far as I understand, you are not using the abstract factory pattern here, it is just an abstract class / interface.

A factory builds and returns an object. In your example, the methods of the class do not build anything, they interact with something, posting, retrieving, updating and deleting posts.

Comment: You're right, sorry. Added the factory class now. Is it using the abstract factory pattern now?

Comment: Yes, you are now using a factory pattern, but not an abstract factory pattern, as your `PostsFactory` class does not derive from an abstract class. Anyway, you could use a callable instead of the class by extracting the `get_posts_factory()` method and making it a function.

Comment: This being said, the name of your method `get_posts_factory()` that may or may not become a function depending on what you choose is not right. This factory does not return a `PostFactory` but an instance of one of `PostManager` subclass. It should then be renamed as `get_posts_manager()` instead. If you decide to keep the class `PostsFactory`, you should then also rename it to `PostsManagerFactory`, but in my opinion, the use of a class is not necessary as it contains only a static method.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have now made those naming changes. I understand now that this is not using abstract factory pattern. If you could re-write this code using abstract factory pattern, how would you do it? Also I dont understand where you said I could use a callable by extracting the method and making it a function. If you could do those both and write an answer, I will accept it as the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following you last comment.

I would not use abstract factory pattern for this use case. May I ask why you want to use it ?

When I suggest to remove the `PostsManagerFactory` class by extracting the `get_posts_manager` to a function, I mean replacing this code snippet

```
class PostsManagerFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def get_posts_manager(use_orm=True) -> PostsManager:
        if use_orm:
            return PostsManagerWithORM()
        else:
            return PostsManagerWithoutORM()
```

with this

```
def get_posts_manager(use_orm=True) -> PostsManager:
    if use_orm:
        return PostsManagerWithORM()
    else:
        return PostsManagerWithoutORM()
```

that you may want to shorten this way

```
def get_posts_manager(use_orm=True) -> PostsManager:
    return PostsManagerWithORM() if use_orm else PostsManagerWithoutORM()
```

Then, you could use it in your code simply by calling the function

```
posts_manager = get_posts_manager() # <----
posts = posts_manager.get_posts()
```

Comment: This is not a real use case. I am just trying out different things and wanted to learn to use different patterns as well. I had some api code lying around which I wrote as part of another tutorial and I thought it would be fun to use some patterns and learn about it more.